# When a derivative is in denominator in a part of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What is relation between $ u,v $ in

$$ \frac{du}{dt} + \frac{ \sin u }{ a^2 u \cot v \, {(dv/dt)} }= 2 k $$

What is a proper substitution or method to start ? $ (a,k) $ are constants.

Comment: What about simply multiplying the equation with $dv/dt$?

Comment: And how to proceed next?